# Scaling SVG dynamically

Tags: html, css, svg

I am not sure how i can work with SVG backgrounds that scale depending on the screen size (full-width) and depending on how much content we have within the `<li>`-tag. I would like to be able to scale to SVG in height, but not in width in that case.

I have been trying to make this work for quite some time now but I don't know how to do it. Could someone help me?

**html**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
ul li {
 height: 6em;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: url(http://leanimpactaward.ch/img/GRAFIK_Accordeon_V1.svg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
    background: url(http://leanimpactaward.ch/img/GRAFIK_Accordeon_V2.svg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3g7n2v5e/3/

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: Hi @Rob I thought it was better readable on jsfiddle. I added the code snippets in the description now.

Comment: First change `background` to `background-image` this may already do the trick. Your SVG should be treated as images... And search the net for 'svg background image' there are plenty examples showing how this works (css-tricks for example, or codepen)

Answer (score -1):

Use the transform:scale(x,y) css property to change the scale of your SVG.

For exemple :

```css
li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: url(http://leanimpactaward.ch/img/GRAFIK_Accordeon_V1.svg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform:scale(1, 0.5);
}
```

Hope it's helping you.

Edit :

It's a better solution if you want no resizing the text :

```css
ul li {
 height: 6em;
 position: relative;
}

li:nth-child(odd)::before {
 content: '';
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
 position: absolute;
 background: url(http://leanimpactaward.ch/img/GRAFIK_Accordeon_V1.svg);
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 transform: scale(1, 0.5);
}

li:nth-child(even)::before {
    content: '';
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
 position: absolute;
 background: url(http://leanimpactaward.ch/img/GRAFIK_Accordeon_V2.svg);
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: scale(1, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This also transforms the text size

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to stretch an svg image, which isn't possible.

Editing your svg file and add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to your svg attributes might do the trick. You might also need to remove width and height.

Comment: May I know why this was downvoted? Didn't I elaborate enough by any chance? If you need a more detailed explanation about this, CSS Tricks has a good article about it: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/